# Why I can't get document via mongoose?

Tags: mongodb, mongoose

I'm getting document via `MongoDB Shell`:

```
db.page_about_love.find()
```

But I can't get document via mongoose. What is wrong?

```
mongoose.connect(db_uri);

var loveSchema = new mongoose.Schema({
    title: String,
    content: String,
    tag: String
});

mongoose.model('page_about_love', loveSchema);
```

---

```
var about = mongoose.model('page_about_love');
about.find(function (err, love) {
    if (err) return console.error(err);
    console.log(love);
});
```

Test output:

```
[]
```

Comment: Use db.page and then tab in the mongodb shell. It probably displays page_about_love and page_about_love*s*, if my assumption is correct. Mongoose turns the name of the model into its plural form for the collection.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

To prevent Mongoose generating a collection name to use, you should be explicit and pass which collection name it should use:

```
var loveSchema = new mongoose.Schema({
    title: String,
    content: String,
    tag: String
}, { collection : 'page_about_love' });
```

Otherwise, Mongoose will apply the `utils.toCollectionName()` function to the model name to determine the collection name, which in your case would yield `page_about_loves` (notice the pluralization).

More information [here](http://mongoosejs.com/docs/guide.html#collection).